# In Android, how can I properly style the new Lollipop button bar?

Tags: android, buttonbar

I know that I should use the `?android:attr/buttonbarbuttonstyle`, but how do I make one of the buttons the default choice that's highlighted in a different color? Is there a way to designate the default button in the XML layout?

Also, will this look the same in the older Android versions if I use Appcompat v21?

**Edit**:
Here's the look I'm going for. The "Explore" button is highlighted (that's what I mean by 'default action'),and the "Share" button is black. If there were more buttons in that button bar, they would be black as well.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by button bar?

Comment: You can assign butons in a layout as a button bar but setting the button styles to attr.buttonBarButtonStyle and the containing layout style to attr/buttonBarStyle. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#buttonBarStyle